# ReflectionException Class App\Http\Controllers\ContactController does not exist Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-5

i am getting this error message

```
 [ReflectionException]
 Class App\Http\Controllers\ContactController does not exist
```

whenever i try to execute any php artisan command in laravel 5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error tells you that `ContactController` doesn't exist or wasn't autoloaded.

Create `ContactController` to fix this. If it already exists, check it's namespace and make sure `ContactController.php` file is in the `app\Http\Controllers` directory.